# UIBarButtonItem doesn't respond to tap

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, wkwebview

I have a `viewController` that's embedded in a `navigationController`. From my `viewController` I programmatically add three `UIBarButtonItem` and a `UISearchBar`. Under the navigationbar I have a `WKWebView` that is covering the whole screen. The issue it that the `UIBarButtonItems` doesn't respond to any clicks before I've taped or in any way interacted with the `WKWebView`. After I tap or scroll the `WKWebView` the `UIBarButtonItems` work fine until I perform a search in the `UISearchBar`. The `UIBarButtonItems` stops responding again until I interact with the `WKWebView`.

I have tried adding `navigationController?.navigationBar.becomeFirstResponder()` in `DidAppear` and in `searchBarTextDidEndEditing` as suggested on some forum post. It has no effect on the issue.

This is what I do in `DidLoad` to initiate the navbar:

```
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "ssl"), for: .search, state: .normal)
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false

    let textField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
    textField?.textAlignment = .center
    textField?.leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.never
    textField?.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
    textField?.keyboardType = .URL
    textField?.autocapitalizationType = .none
    textField?.leftView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let back = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(naviagteBack))
    let forward = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "forward"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(naviagteForward))
    let reload = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "reload"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(navigateReload))

    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    reload.tintColor = .black
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = reload

    back.tintColor = .lightGray
    forward.tintColor = .lightGray

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [back, forward]
```

I want the `UIBarButtonItems` to be active all of the time. Not just after I interact with the `WKWebView`. And no, it has nothing to do with the capabilities of `goBack()` e.t.c. I have added `print("!")` to the button functions and it outputs nothing while in the "unactivated" state.

Comment: There does not appear to be anything wrong with the code you posted. You may need to post more code the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: What is your updateSearchResults function?

Comment: I don't think that the SearchBar is causing the issue. I've commented out `navigationItem.titleView = searchBar` and I still have the issue. I tried to add the buttons in storyboard and it works perfectly. Somethings with the adding of the buttons seems to be the problem.

Comment: I figured it out. I had `let back = UIBarButtonItem...` outside the `didLoad` function. Moved it there and it works!